# PrimeFaces: Calendar not working if "timeOnly='true'" and "minDate" & "maxDate" are on the same date

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar, timepicker

I have the following test page using PrimeFaces v3.5.14:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test page</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:calendar pattern="MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mma" value="#{mrBean.date}"
                        mindate="#{mrBean.minDate}" maxdate="#{mrBean.maxDate}" />

            <p:calendar pattern="HH:mm" value="#{mrBean.date}" timeOnly="true" 
                        mindate="#{mrBean.minDate}" maxdate="#{mrBean.maxDate}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is my `@ManagedBean`:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {
    private Date minDate;
    private Date maxDate;
    private Date date;

    @PostConstruct
    public void prepareServices() {
        this.minDate = new Date();
        this.maxDate = new DateTime().plusHours(1).toDate();
    }

    // Getters and Setters   
}
```

In brief, if `minDate` and `maxDate` happen to be on the same date, `<p:calendar>` does not appear if `timeOnly="true"`.

I'd be very grateful if you could tell me if this is a bug of PrimeFaces or I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `mindate` and `maxdate` are breaking the second calendar because it's supposed to be `timeOnly`. Remove that attributes and you'll see that works. So, let's say, your first calendar works with dates, second one does with time.

If you want to bound the selected time between now and an hour after, calculate the current time in the server and use `minHour` and `maxHour`. That will set your selected time in a date starting from `Jan 1, 1970`. If you want you can combine it with the selection you make in the other calendar.

Of course, doing it that way has its cons. It allows you to select every single minute inside the same hour (remember you are bounding only the hour), even if it's already past. To achieve what you want your first calendar seems to be the best choice.

---

*Tested with PrimeFaces 3.5*